# Data scraping using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I developed a script using Python to scrape name of phone from this URL https://www.jumia.com.ng/mobile-phones/

Here is my script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/mobile-phones/' 
uClient =uReq(my_url) #open connection.. grab the page
page_html = uClient.read() #load the content into a varaible
uClient.close()  #close the console
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #it does the html parser
phone_name = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"name"}) #grabs each phone name
print (phone_name)
```

My expected result should be something like this:

```
Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey
```

but what I get is this :

```
<span class="name" dir="ltr">Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey</span>.
```

How do I extract the text from this `<span class="name" dir="ltr">Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey</span>`?

Comment: what you are getting and what is expected are same in your question

Comment: Did you read [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: use python requests. It is better than urllib

Comment: what you are getting and what is expected are same in your question ... I'm getting this <span class="name" dir= "ltr"> Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey</span>. My expected result should just be this Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey.Thanks for your response

Comment: Did you read BeautifulSoup documentation?   No... I'm doing that now... Hope it helps... Thanks for your response..

Comment: Ok, I got your problem check my answer

Comment: @akash.. Thank you for your response. Please can you write the whole script for me to inspect... I add your line of script to my codes and I'm getting invalid syntax error. thanks

Comment: It is working well @akash.. I have a bonus question... How do I scrape the other 24 pages since this is just page 1.. Thanks

Comment: you need to iterate your url like this `https://www.jumia.com.ng/mobile-phones/?page=2`, you can append variable and increment it till the last page

Comment: Can I automate the iteration in my script say.. add a loop statement that will change the url automatically

Comment: yes, that's how it should be done

Comment: Can you give me a clue on that or better still help me with the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract name, use `.text`

```
>>> for phone_name in page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"name"}):
        print(phone_name.text)

Boom J8 5.5 Inch (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android Lollipop 5.1 13MP + 5MP Smartphone - White (MWFS)
Marathon M5 Mini 5.0-Inch IPS (2GB, 16GB ROM) Android 5.1 Lollipop, 13MP + 8MP Smartphone - Grey
```

Therefore your script should be like :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/mobile-phones/' 
uClient =uReq(my_url) #open connection.. grab the page
page_html = uClient.read() #load the content into a varaible
uClient.close()  #close the console
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #it does the html parser
for phone_name in page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"name"}):
    print(phone_name.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's old I know, but for people facing a similar challenge, you can use a robust Jumia scraper I built on Apify - https://apify.com/microworlds/jumia-scraper